# Can't get Django settings inside of my view

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

I'm trying to pull stripe settings from my cookiecutter base.py, and it's not working. I'm not sure if I have not set my view correctly, or what.

I'm testing all of this locally, and I have installed stripe via pip and added it to my installed apps (not sure if I needed to do that)

here is my urls.py for the payment view

```
 path("payment/", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pages/Payment.html"), name="payment")
```

And here is my views.py

```
class PaymentView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'Payment.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):  # new
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['key'] = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    return context
```

I've got the following in my base.py

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = 'sk_test_xxxx'
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = 'pk_test_xxxxx'
```

I feel my issue isn't that I have the keys in the wrong place. I may just have my view class not named correctly. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: How do you import `settings`? Also what do you mean by _"it's not working"_?

Comment: from django.conf import settings

Comment: And stripe is saying I still haven't supplied the publishable key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url is a generic `TemplateView` which renders the template specified.

To use your custom view you have to specify it in the url

```
 path("payment/", PaymentView.as_view(), ...
```

Comment: My view is rendering fine, it's my class that isn't apparently talking to the view? So that's why the stripe key isn't being sent out

Comment: You've defined a view that adds the setting to the context but your url is just using the generic template view that doesn't...

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean

Comment: That was it! Thanks!